# Remote Dual Booting

Tags: dual-boot

I manage an IT lab of 37 computers with dual booting (Dell Optiplex with Windows 10 LTSC and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on separate drives).
If Wake-On LAN from another PC: default boot via Grub is Windows, Ubuntu needs on-site presence.
Is there a way to remotely select a desired OS to boot? Either the PC is powered off, or a reboot on any of the two systems is needed.
Many thanks,
Alex